# When can the present perfect continuous be used with 'ever since'?

Tags: perfect-aspect, perfect-continuous

Advanced Grammar In Use by Martin Hewings starts with the following in Unit 6 'Present perfect continuous and present perfect':

> We use the present perfect continuous to express the idea of an activity (a task, piece of work, etc.) in progress until recently or until the time of speaking:
>
> - **Have** you **been working** in the garden *all day*? You look exhausted.
> - She **'s been writing** the book *since she was in her twenties* and at last it's finished.
>
> Notice that we often use time expressions to say how long the activity has been in progress.

The first sentence I think can be said either while the listener is still working in the garden or after the work is done, whereas the second one I think can only be said after the writing is done (because it's mentioned that it's finished). Am I right?

Now, with that in mind, is the present perfect continuous compatible with 'ever since' as shown in (1) and (2)?

> (1) ***Have** you **been working** in the garden **ever since this morning**? You look exhausted.* [*You* may or may not be working in the garden at the time of speaking.]
>
> (2) *She **'s been writing** the book **ever since she was in her twenties** and at last it's finished.* [*She* is not writing the book at the time of speaking.]

The purpose of this question is to figure out whether the time expression 'ever since' can be used only when the situation being described is still in progress at the time of speaking.

**Analysis A**: 'Ever since' can be used only when the situation being described is still in progress at the time of speaking. Therefore, (1) is grammatically accurate only if the listener is still working in the garden at the time of speaking, whereas (2) is grammatically inaccurate under any context imaginable.

**Analysis B**: 'Ever since' can be used even when the situation being described is not in progress any longer at the time of speaking. Therefore, both (1) and (2) are grammatically accurate regardless of further context.

Which analysis is correct? And Why?

Comment: In the second example, it is just as natural (if not _more_ natural) if she’s still writing the book. It sounds just a tiny bit odd to me to add “and at last it’s finished” instead of “and it’s still not finished” (this is regardless of whether you use _since_ or _ever since_: the example from the book is a bit off for me as well). In the first example, _ever since_ isn’t a superb fit, because the intensifying _ever_ hints at a longer period of time than just ‘since this morning’. But both are perfectly grammatical and not entirely unlikely to be heard in normal conversation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the feedback. But I don't understand why you'd think AGIU's second example sounds off. As far as I know, the present perfect continuous can certainly describe a situation that is not ongoing at the time of speaking. For example, you can say "It's been raining, but it's now sunny."

Comment: Yes, but not with a defined starting point. That’s just the perfect in general, not specific to the perfect continuous. “I’ve been in Rome, but I’m not anymore” is fine, but “I’ve been in Rome since Wednesday, but I’m not anymore” doesn’t work. Similarly, “It’s been raining, but now it’s sunny” is fine, but “It’s been raining since this morning, but now it’s sunny” is off, though less definitely so. Even more jarring is “I’ve been sitting here waiting for three hours, but I’m not anymore”.

Comment: “In progress until recently” is critical to the author’s description of when the present perfect continuous is appropriate. How recently? Does the author give examples of when the criterion is not met?  Clearly it cannot be used with actions completed further in the past. What is said on this?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could you cite a reference that supports your claim that this type of the perfect cannot be used "with a defined starting point"? I've never heard of such a restriction. If you're saying it's not just a bit odd but it "doesn't work", are you claiming that AGIU made a mistake of using an ungrammatical sentence?

Comment: @Xanne I agree with you that the phrase is critical. But I think what's critical is not "until how recently" but is that "until recently" does not mean "until now".

Comment: @JK I don’t have any sources to hand, but are you saying you find my examples (especially the last one) unremarkable? That you find “I’ve worked here for three years, but I don’t anymore” to sound natural? Because it sounds completely unnatural and extremely jarring to me, and I’ve never heard a native speaker utter such a construction. (“Defined starting point” was not really well stated. It doesn’t have to be a starting point, but if a perfect construction is given a period, to me that period must by necessity continue into the relevant ‘now’ point.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I hate to make a blanket statement about your examples, which seem to be evolving every time you write another comment. As you have suggested, even your own examples do not sound exactly the same to you in terms of their acceptability. I also don't think your examples are the same as AGIU's second example in acceptability. I thank you for raising the issue about the possibility that AGIU's second example might be problematic. But I cannot accept that it is problematic especially when both the second and third edition of the book have this example.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How about this hypothetical interview of one of the first buyers of a new iPhone who endured long overnight lines outside an Apple retail store? The interviewee is being interviewed coming out of the store with a new iPhone: "I've been waiting since midnight, but it's been worth it." Do you find this awkward?

Comment: @JK2 Not awkward, no, but I do find it just slightly off. If I’d seen the quote on its own, I would have expected it to have been said just _before_ he went into the store to buy his new toy, not after coming out. The progressive form does seem to be much more obliging than the simple perfect in allowing periods that have already finished, but there is still an element of something not quite right about it to me. Coming out of the store, I would have found it more natural if he’d said, “I’d been waiting since midnight, but it was worth it”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. So I think the reason why your example "I’ve been sitting here waiting for three hours, but I’m not anymore." sounds incongruous is not because the present perfect continuous (combined with "for three hours") describes a situation not obtaining at the moment of speaking, but because somehow "but I'm not anymore" is semantically incompatible with the previous clause.// And I agree with you that the present perfect continuous may be treated a bit differently than its non-continuous counterpart.

Comment: But those are just two sides of the same coin, aren’t they? If the present perfect continuous (combined with “for three hours”) _could_ describe a situation not obtaining the moment of speaking, then there would be no semantic incompatibility. The fact that there is (to me) a semantic incompatibility just means that this form of the verb can’t describe a state no longer obtaining.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What I'm saying is that the semantic incompatibility arises from the incongruity **not** between the present perfect continuous (combined with “for three hours”) and a situation not obtaining at the moment of speaking, **but** between this specific clauses "I’ve been sitting here waiting for three hours" and "but I’m not anymore”.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need any fancy analysis, it is literally the definition of "ever since" that it is still happenning:

> A. I. 1. b. Limited by a following adverb, preposition, or
>   conjunction, as in ever after(-ward), ever before, ever since, ever
>   yet, etc.: **throughout all the time** before or after a specified point
>   in time. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65307?redirectedFrom=ever%20since#eid5132605) (emphasis mine)

That said, regardless of whether they may technically be grammatical, as a style matter, I think both of your example sentences would both be improved by removing the redundant "ever." Both have a clearly operating "since" plus temporal pointer that does not need "ever" for clarity or for intensifying (in fact, the intensifying sense of "ever since" makes little sense in the first one, give the short duration). Even in longer scales of time, the "ever" may not be needed as an intensifier. Consider:

> Since the dawn of time, man has yearned to destroy the sun. I will do
>   the next best thing; block it out! ["Who Shot Mr Burns? (Part One)." Groening, Matt et al. *The Simpsons* S 06 E 25. 1995.]

While in this case, "ever since" would make sense as an intensifier, it is not required for either meaning or intent. Compare:

> I once ran into a tree head-first on my bike. I have worn a helmet
>   ever since.

In this example, "ever" is necessary in order to clearly establish the temporal relationship, though "ever since" could be replaced with "since then" or "since that time," much as in your example cases.

Comment: Please be advised that the question is not about whether 'ever' is necessary but whether 'ever' is compatible (be it necessary or not). That's why the title is "When **can** the present perfect continuous be used with 'ever since'?", not "When **must** the present perfect continuous be used with 'ever since'?".

Comment: And the answer, as with all cases of a language where grammar is defined by use is 'it depends.' There is a clear and documented case to be made against ever in some cases, but there is a less clear, but no less important case against it in other uses. The answer would be misleading if it simply accepted that the cases are correct on a technicality, when they would both sound off to an editor.